# Error when import Custom Fonts in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I try to Install the Custom fonts but my console tells me that I got an error in the pubspec.yaml file.
and the Error message I got is:

*flutter pub get
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Unexpected key assets ((String)) under font.
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at C:\Users\Divyansh\Desktop\Development\flutter\Expense_Planner\pubspec.yaml
exit code 1*

and this is the part  I added in pubspec.yaml file:

```
fonts: 
  - family: OpenSans
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
      - asset: fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
        weight: 700
  - family: Quicksand
    fonts:
      - asset:  fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf
      - asset: fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf
        weight: 700
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo "assets", this is your corrected pubspec:

```yaml
fonts: 
  - family: OpenSans
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
      - asset: fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
        weight: 700
  - family: Quicksand
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf
      - asset: fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf # You had a typo in this line
        weight: 700
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the typo mentioned by @Guilherme don't forget to import the folder that contains your fonts in your *pubspec.yaml* file:

```
 # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - folderThatContainsYourFonts/
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) pkg by flutter rather than downloading each font and putting it in pubsec.yaml file.